# Linux bridge - hello and hold timers

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, network-programming

I am working on a small Linux embedded network bridged device (with 2.6 Tickless Kernel).

I am trying to reduce cpu wakeup time (When the system is idle) and check which timers can be avoided.

I have noticed that although STP is explicitly disabled on the bridge, hello timer and hold timers are expiring every 2 sec (default time).

```
echo 1 > /proc/timer_stats; sleep 30; echo 0 > /proc/timer_stats ; cat /proc/timer_stats

Timer Stats Version: v0.2
Sample period: 30.016 s
  1,     1 init             hrtimer_start_range_ns (hrtimer_wakeup)
  15,     0 swapper          br_transmit_config (br_hold_timer_expired)
  15,     0 swapper          run_timer_softirq (br_hello_timer_expired)
  15,     5 events/0         worker_thread (delayed_work_timer_fn)
  2D,     5 events/0         neigh_periodic_work (delayed_work_timer_fn)
  1,   502 sleep            hrtimer_start_range_ns (hrtimer_wakeup)
  5,     0 swapper          run_timer_softirq (sync_supers_timer_fn)
  5,    10 bdi-default      bdi_forker_task (process_timeout)
  2D,     5 events/0         neigh_periodic_work (delayed_work_timer_fn)
  1,     5 events/0         worker_thread (delayed_work_timer_fn)
  1,   548 sleep            hrtimer_start_range_ns (hrtimer_wakeup)
63 total events, 2.098 events/sec
```

Looking at the Kernel bridge code, it seems that these timers are set regardless of the STP mode (disable/enable).

One approach could be to make the timers expire time longer (brctl sethello br0 30), it is ok though not ideal.

A different approach would be to patch the kernel so timer initialization will not take place when STP is disabled, patching the kernel is also not ideal.

Is there a reason that these timers are initialized even though STP is disabled ?

Does anyone have a different idea/approach ?

Thanks